# Docker container in CircleCI not showing files even though volume appears mounted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci

This is the docker-compose command and the results:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-base.yml -f docker-compose-test.yml run api sh -c 'pwd && ls'
Starting test-db ... done
/usr/src/api
node_modules
```

I then inspected the most recent container id:

```
$ docker inspect  --format='{{json .Mounts}}' e150beeef85c
[
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/circleci/project",
    "Destination": "/usr/src/api",
    "Mode": "rw",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  },
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "4f86174ca322af6d15489da91f745861815a02f5b4e9e879ef5375663b9defff",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/4f86174ca322af6d15489da91f745861815a02f5b4e9e879ef5375663b9defff/_data",
    "Destination": "/usr/src/api/node_modules",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  }
]
```

Which means, these files are not appearing:

```
$ ls /home/circleci/project
Dockerfile  docker-compose-base.yml  docker-compose-prod.yml  migrations     nodemon-debug.json  package-lock.json  src   test-db.env  tsconfig.build.json  tslint.json
README.md   docker-compose-dev.yml   docker-compose-test.yml  nest-cli.json  nodemon.json        package.json       test  test.env     tsconfig.json
```

Why could this be?

**Update:** I should mention that all this works fine on my local dev environment. The above is failing on CircleCI.

When I inspect the differences between the containers, the only major things that I see is that my dev environment runs Docker 19 using `overlay2` graph driver and the above failing environment runs Docker 17 using `aufs` graph driver.

**Update 2:** Actual docker-compose files:

```
# docker-compose-base.yml
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: api
```

```
# docker-compose-test.yml
version: '3'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: lb_lbnet

services:
  test-db:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: test-db
    env_file:
      - ./test-db.env # uses POSTGRES_DB and POSTGRES_PASSWORD to create a fresh db with a password when first run

  api:
    restart: 'no'
    env_file:
      - test.env
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/api
      - /usr/src/api/node_modules
    depends_on:
      - test-db
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
      - 3000:3000
    command: npm run start:debug
```

And finally `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:11

WORKDIR /usr/src/api

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

# not using an execution list here so we get shell variable substitution
CMD npm run start:$NODE_ENV
```

Comment: Can you include your actual `docker-compose.yml` files in the question?

Comment: @DavidMaze Apologies. I updated the question docker-compose files and Dockerfile.

Comment: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/#mounting-folders

Answer (score 0):

As @allisongranemann pointed out, [CircleCI states](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/#mounting-folders):

> It is not possible to mount a volume from your job space into a
>   container in Remote Docker (and vice versa).

The original reason why I wanted to mount the project directory to docker was that in the development environment, I could change code quickly and run tests without rebuilding the container.

With this limitation, the solution I went with was to remove volumes mounting from `docker-compose-test.yml` as follow:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test-db:
    image: postgres:11
    container_name: test-db
    env_file:
      - ./test-db.env # uses POSTGRES_DB and POSTGRES_PASSWORD to create a fresh db with a password when first run

  api:
    restart: 'no'
    env_file:
      - test.env
    depends_on:
      - test-db
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
      - 3000:3000
    command: npm run start:debug
```

And I also added `docker-compose-test-dev.yml` that adds the volumes for the dev environment:

```
version: '3'

services:
  api:
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/api
```

Finally, to run tests on the dev environment, I run:

`docker-compose -f docker-compose-base.yml -f docker-compose-test.yml -f docker-compose-test-dev.yml run api npm run test:e2e`